# Ajax request performance degradation

Tags: ajax, primefaces, progress-bar, wildfly, mojarra

I have Wildfly 11 with Mojarra (2.2.16) JSF implementation.

On page i have Primefaces progressbar with delay=1000 (1s).

ProgressBar active time ~10 min.

Problem:
[image]

Comment: Every call to update ProgressBar state process new DynamicActions from FacesContext.
For example:
FirstCall - DynamicActions list size = 100
N call - DynamicActions list size = 100 + N * X

Comment: So improve that... we cannot help you with that... Especially without any [mcve]